# Get number of sheets in Open Office with Java

Tags: java, openoffice.org

I am using Java to automate the creation and modification of Open Office Calc documents.

I was wondering how to get the number of sheets in a spreadsheet. I can't seem to find any Count, Length, size or similar functions.

Here is my code. Thanks in advance!

```
  public static void openDocument(String filename)
{
    try
    {           
        // Get the remote office component context
        xContext = Bootstrap.bootstrap();

        // Get the remote office service manager
        XMultiComponentFactory xMCF = xContext.getServiceManager();

        // Get the root frame (i.e. desktop) of openoffice framework.
        oDesktop = xMCF.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", xContext);

        // Desktop has 3 interfaces. The XComponentLoader interface provides ability to load components.
        XComponentLoader xCompLoader = (XComponentLoader) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XComponentLoader.class,
                oDesktop);

        PropertyValue[] loadProps = new PropertyValue[0];

        xSpreadsheetComponent = xCompLoader.loadComponentFromURL(getUpdatedPath(filename), "_blank", 0, loadProps);

        xStorable = (XStorable) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XStorable.class, xSpreadsheetComponent);

        xSpreadsheetDocument = (XSpreadsheetDocument) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XSpreadsheetDocument.class,
                xSpreadsheetComponent);

        xSpreadsheets = xSpreadsheetDocument.getSheets();
        // Need code here to get number of sheets
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `.getCount()`?

Comment: For which control? xSpreadSheets? If yes, there is no such method unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue using this:

```
int numberOfSheets = xSpreadsheets.getElementNames().length;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment (since I do not know the correct syntax for Java - maybe you need to do a .queryInterface on xSpreadsheets?), but posting as an answer to include an image. Using Bernard Marcelly's object inspection tool XRay (http://bernard.marcelly.perso.sfr.fr/index2.html) shows that an XSpreadsheets object has a method .getCount().  I tested this method using OpenOffice Basic and it works as expected.

[image: Xray window of XSpreadsheets object]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, when I try this in Eclipse, I get "The method getCount() is undefined for the type XSpreadsheets".

Comment: I though of doing a loop by trying to access sheets by index and waiting for a invalid index exception, but that looks pretty foolish to me :)

Comment: Thank you sir, you answer made me it look at the problem differently and I found what I was looking for :)